# Add geckodriver to PATH on Windows 11

Tags: selenium, geckodriver, selenium-firefoxdriver

To complete a project using Selenium, I first need to add Geckodriver to PATH. I have read many articles about adding elements to PATH, but none of them end up working (I follow the steps and add a new element to PATH, but when I run my program I get the `'geckodriver' executable needs to be in PATH` error.

[image]

1: I first download this version of Geckodriver from here: https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases

[image]

2: I extract the folder and add it to the PATH

3: When I run my program, I get the same error `Message: 'geckodriver' executable needs to be in PATH.`

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Selenium using Python - Geckodriver executable needs to be in PATH](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40208051/selenium-using-python-geckodriver-executable-needs-to-be-in-path)

Comment: Can you post your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do need to add an environment variable for the firefox driver.
          `String exePath = ".\\lib\\geckodriver.exe"; System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", exePath); driver = new FirefoxDriver();`

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to add a new environment variable, just move the file `geckodriver.exe` to your python folder, which in my case is

```
C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310
```

Then to start the firefox driver just run

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
```